# change the dropEffect of a drag

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I am using [ngx drag and drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-drag-drop) which is using the default HTML5 dnd api.

I have a list of object, when I move them, my event and the drop effect are type `"copy"`
I am trying to find a way to make the event be a `"move"` instead because that what is the drag and drop action supposed to be, and I want my OnMove event to fire

I tried change when I start the drag

```
  onDragStart(event:DragEvent, card:KanbanCard) {
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

But this doesn't work

```
<div class="kanban-column-container">
<p class="title"><strong>{{column.name}}</strong></p>
<button mat-button (click)="addCard();">Add Card</button>
<div class="list"  
dndDropzone
(dndDrop)="onDrop($event)">
    <!-- PLACEHOLDER for drag & drop. Removed on DOM LOAD AUTOMATICALLY -->
    <div class="card-placeholder" dndPlaceholderRef>
        placeholder
    </div> 

    <div *ngFor="let card of _cards"
    [dndDraggable]="card"
    (dndEffectAllowed)="move"
    (dndStart)="onDragStart($event, card)"
    (dndCanceled)="onDragCanceled($event, card)"
    (dndMoved)="onMoved($event)"
    (dndEnd)="onDragEnd($event, card)"
    [hidden]="card.hidden">
        <kanban-card-component [card]="card"></kanban-card-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly u did it wrong.
first of it suppose to be [] and not () cos its not a function.
secound if you want to put a value it soppuse to be like you put and Object so this way will work.

```
<div class="kanban-column-container">
<p class="title"><strong>{{column.name}}</strong></p>
<button mat-button (click)="addCard();">Add Card</button>
<div class="list"  
dndDropzone
(dndDrop)="onDrop($event)">
    <!-- PLACEHOLDER for drag & drop. Removed on DOM LOAD AUTOMATICALLY -->
    <div class="card-placeholder" dndPlaceholderRef>
        placeholder
    </div> 

    <div *ngFor="let card of _cards"
    [dndDraggable]="card"
    [dndEffectAllowed]="'move'" <-- like this
    (dndStart)="onDragStart($event, card)"
    (dndCanceled)="onDragCanceled($event, card)"
    (dndMoved)="onMoved($event)"
    (dndEnd)="onDragEnd($event, card)"
    [hidden]="card.hidden">
        <kanban-card-component [card]="card"></kanban-card-component>
    </div>
</div>
```